# How do I create an IAM user with privileges to view the account's billing information?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-billing

I added both **Administrator** and **Billing** policies to the **admin** group that I created, and added a user **admin1** to this group. When I login as **admin1**, I get an error message  saying I don't have privileges to see billing information of the account. What am I missing?

**Use Case :** In my startup, I want to have all my developers have access to "Root Account's Billing information" so they know the costs incurred. Also, you wouldn't want to login-as as root user to just view the billing information, correct.

How do I create an IAM user with  privileges to view the account's billing information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to granting billing privileges to IAM users, you have to login as root and **activate IAM user access to the Billing Console**.

See: [Granting Access to Your Billing Information and Tools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/grantaccess.html)

---

[image]